# Login form save password data is reflect in some other form password type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coldfusion

I'm facing the issue as " If I'm saving username and password while login in my browser It's will reflect in some other pages UI those are having password type.

For example, I'm having login.cfm while login with that page I'm saving the authentication details in my browser.  While I'm hitting my stripe.cfm page it's having a login username and password details in stripe username and password form fields. For your reference, I've attached screenshot ( login.PNG & stirpeReflect.png ) about login and stripe form you can see the details.

**Login page :**
[image]

**Stripe page :** 
[image]

Note: I've tried to use autocompleted="off" in login form & stripe form. But it's not helped me to escape from this issue.

I've tested it in both Firefox and Chrome also...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `autofill="false"` instead of `autocomplete`

Comment: I think you need to use autocomplete="off" nested of autocompleted="off"....try to set it for form, and your input....also you can save fill in local-storage and fill it manual dependence of login page

Answer (score 1):

Hi @johan and @ Anees Hikmat Abu Hmiad thanks a lot for your attention on my question.

I've fixed it by adding **autocomplete="new-password"** instead of **autocomplete="off"**. So that it's consider as separate form fields.

**Example :** 
In my stripe.cfm form I've added a **autocomplete="new-password"** for my password input field. Now it's not consider my login authentication while saved in browser.

Thank you!.